# Angular states point to correct controller but not html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am just setting up a simple Angular app as I've done countless times. I added a home state and a separate state for a note taking app, yet neither states are displaying/injecting the html partials into the ui-view. I think it might be an issue with my ui-router setup, but I cannot find the issue. I console log from my controllers and they trigger correctly, so the states are clearly pointing to the right controllers.

**Index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="factory.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

**config**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateURL: './home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .state('list', {
      url: '/list',
      templateURL: '/list.html',
      controller: 'listCtrl'
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('listCtrl', function($scope, myFactory) {
  console.log("list working!");
  $scope.items = myFactory.items
  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.unshift($scope.newItem);
    $scope.newItem = "";

  }
})

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("home working!");

  $scope.test = 'test'
})
```

My home state should load a partial containing:

```
<div>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
</div>
```

Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/ngHYDtx0VBe2YPlBeJ3t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It has to be

```
  templateUrl: './home.html',
```

Also, it is not desirable to use relative paths for templates, './home.html' and 'home.html' will be cached internally as two different templates.

Comment: I have now changed this and yet am experiencing the same issue

Comment: Do see any http request made for your templates in the browser console, eg chrome network tab in debugging tools?

Comment: @CharlesWatson Since you're not providing plunker to replicate the issue, you may check the console for errors and network tab to check if the templates are being loaded.

Comment: Console only outputs my controller console log. Network tab shows that the html partial never loads

Comment: And it is ok with templateUrl instead of templateURL: http://plnkr.co/edit/1pbkVdiGOQBAiAxjzSXe?p=preview